# Is existence of this graph consistent with ZFC?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, lo.logic

Is existence of the following graph consistent with $\sf ZFC$.

The graph is directed upwards and acyclic, children nodes can be connected to ONE parent only, and it is not the union of separate (disjoint) graphs.

The nodes are ordered triplets $(n,x,i)$ of a natural number $n$ and sets $x,i$; we call the first projection of each node as its *decoration*, while the second projection as its *value*, the third projection $i$ is the separation factor.

The decoration of each node is the number of nodes in the maximal path below it.

Every node decorated with $n$ must have separate paths reaching it from below of all natural lengths below $n$.

The last property about decorations is that for every natural $n$ there is a node decorated with it.

If $b$ is the parent node of node $a$ then the vaule of node $b$ is the power set of the value of node $a$.

The idea of the separation factor $i$ is to ensure the disjointness of paths, I think it ought to be the decoration of the path above it (i.e. the closure parent-hood over it), where by a decoration of a path it is meant the set of all decorations of nodes in that path.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing it by intersection of all sets containing the graph $\{(n, \mathcal P^n (\emptyset), \{m \in \mathbb N \mid m > n\}) \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$, and that are closed under complesion of any graph contained in it, complesion is defined as adding to each $k> 0 $ decorated node of it $k-1$ separate paths from below to that node.